# Completion of topological vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces

It is known that if you have a Hausdorff topological vector space $X$, then it embeds bi-continuously in a complete topological vector space.

I was wondering if someone knew an example of a non-Hausdorff topological vector space which cannot be embedded bi-continuously in a complete one.

(here completion is with respects to Cauchy filters)

Comment: Has anyone stuudied non-Hausdoff tvs's?

Comment: I really do not know. It was just out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't think any useful theorems can be proved for non Hausdorff tvs's, so I suggest you delete this post.

Comment: You think neither counterexample to things like this can be easily found?